# Subtraction function on SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to calculate the difference in miles of my trucks based off a timeframe.
They have their odometers reported in our database every 15 minutes or so.
I believe the two primary columns will be Unit_ID, Readingdate, Odometer 
This is where I am at now.

```
(SELECT ODOMETER 
FROM ODOHIST O 
WHERE O.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID
AND READINGDATE < READINGDATE - 21 DAYS 
ORDER BY READINGDATE DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
 AS ODOMETER,
```

Comment: Since odometers don't go in reverse. Why not calculate max - min for a given unit in a given time frame?

Comment: Well I would like to do something like this: Odometer (current date) - Odometer (21 days ago)

Comment: yOU SIR HAVE SOLVED MY PROBLEM, THANK YOU GOOD MAN

Comment: The SQL standard to specify an interval is `interval '21' day` not `21 days`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely follow or have all of the info to solve it, but what about something like this:

```
(SELECT min(ODOMETER)
FROM ODOHIST O 
WHERE O.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID AND DATE = READINGDATE - 21)
 AS MIN_ODOMETER,
(SELECT max(ODOMETER)
FROM ODOHIST O 
WHERE O.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID AND DATE = READINGDATE)
 AS MAX_ODOMETER
```

Then take the difference between the two.